# Farseer DebugView not rendering on top

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

For some reason when I try to use Farseer's debug view, it is always rendered underneath my textures. I can see it rendered, but it's always rendered underneath everything. I checked my code, and it is rendered after the level is drawn. Is that normal? Is there a way to make it rendered on top?

**Screenshot:**

[image: DebugView bounding box rendered underneath Texture2D]

**Code:**

```
// Draws Texture2D objects to screen
level.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch, showTextures);

// ...

Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0,
    ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width),
    ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height),
    0, 0, 1);

debugView.RenderDebugData(ref projection);
```

Comment: The problem is most likely your Spritebatch sort modes.

Comment: Does this mean XNA renders certain types of rendered objects, such as the "vector-like" debugView stuff, underneath the pixel-based Texture2D's? How do I change this?

Comment: Show me your spritebatch.begin calls.  If you do not specify a spritesortmode, it defaults to deferred mode.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx

Comment: Saying that the debugView is "vector-like" is meaningless in an XNA application.  Farseer is drawing textured triangles, just like everything else.  My off-the-cuff guess is that Jon is right and you're doing something like sorting by texture.

Comment: I was using the default `spriteBatch.Begin();` with no arguments. If I use `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode, BlendState)`, which SpriteSortMode should I use? Deferred didn't fix it.

Comment: I figured it out. I called `spriteBatch.End()` right after drawing the textures, then called `spriteBatch.Begin()` again for the debugView. Thanks!